# A question about git and github

Tags: git, version-control

I have a problem. I forked a project in github.com. I made my changes, commited it and pushed to the original (what I Forked) repo. But in the original repo there are many changes, so I'd like to merge this with my own fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add that original repo to your remotes.

Use [`git remote add`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) to do so.
From the [GitHub help page on forks](http://help.github.com/forking/):

> Once the clone is complete your repo will have a remote named “**`origin`**” that points to your fork on github. **Don’t let the name confuse you, this does not point to the original repo you forked from**.
>   To help you keep track of that repo we will add another remote named “upstream”:

```
$ cd github-services
$ git remote add upstream git://github.com/pjhyett/github-services.git
$ git fetch upstream
```